# ExtJS 4 - bbar collapsing after file upload thru 'file' widget

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm working with ExtJS 4.1.1. I've a 'filefield' config on the bottom bar of a panel. To handle the upload operation, I'm embedding the widget into a dynamically created form. However after the form submit, the bbar collapses. I've added alerts in all the listeners that can be called for removal, and none of them are invoked. The behaviour is perplexing. Any suggestions, please ? I've attached screen shots of the bbar before and after upload.

```js
bbar: [{        
    xtype: 'filefield',
    id: 'fileUploadBtn',
    buttonOnly: true,
    buttonText: 'Preview Local File',
    buttonConfig: {
        iconCls: 'folder'
    },
    hideLabel: true,
    listeners: {
        change: function(field, value) {            
            onUploadClick(field, docUploadUrl, callback);
        } 
    }
}]

function onUploadClick(fileField, url, callback) {  
    var uploadForm = Ext.widget('form', {
        autoDestroy: false
        ,items: [fileField]
    });

    uploadForm.submit({
        //...
    }); 
};
```

[image: bbar before upload operation]

[image: collapsed bbar after file upload]

Comment: Found out 'removed' event is being called on the filefield widget. I reverted to ExtJS 4.0.7 where it is working perfectly without this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Filefield expects to be in a form.
Try inserting it in a form layout, and maybe this won't happen:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File

Comment: I've done what the OP is doing with tbar, but never experienced this issue.